# Directory structure inside the training container in AWS sagemaker notebook

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-lightning

How can I make the directory structure inside the training container matches the local structure in sagemaker notebook in the script mode?

For example, I have local directory structure shown in the screenshot below[image],
and I want to import functions from the src directory in flow_conflearn.py.